# Can't add a tag using system.io file, as i need it to be cast as a fileinfo object later in my code

Tags: c#, listview, treeview, fileinfo

The tag to the file anode is causing errors with the directory anode, is this because they are one and the same? Also i think That the casting from the tag to a fileinfo object isn't working. Any suggestions as to how to get the fileinfo into the nodes that the user selects to populate a listview?

```
//see code below where attempts made to add tags
foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
        {
            aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
            aNode.Tag = subDir;
            aNode.ImageKey = "Folder";
            aNode.ImageIndex = 0;
            aNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
            subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();

            if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
            {
                GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
            }

            //add files to treeview
            foreach (var file in subDir.GetFiles())
            {
                if(file.Name.Contains(".rfa"))
                {
                aNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name)); 
           //cant add a tag to the file only to the directory
             aNode.Tag = file;               

                }
            }

            nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
        }
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate, go to:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6239644/120391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In order to check the file's extension, it's a better practice to use:

```
file.Extension.Equals(".rfa", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

2) You're modifying the aNode 'Tag' property, which is probably what causing your problem, try modifying it as follows:

```
aNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name){Tag=file});
```

3) IMHO, you should not keep the FileInfo/DirectoryInfo object in the 'Tag', rather use the path itself

4) If you simply want to display the directory's structure in a treeview, look at the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239644/120391
[You can easily modify it to display only '.rfa' files]

Comment: Thanx nissim sorry about the head was it a horrific crash? I have already implemented #2 in my code i am in your debt, except when you wear that cronie Nixon mask.

Comment: You should see my butt