# Populate TreeView with files and directories but without hidden folders and files

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, directory-structure

so I am trying to populate a treeview with folders and files from a given directory, but when the given path is a drive, example: path = "E:/", it gives me a UnauthorizedAccessException error. The code comes from this other question here: [Populate TreeView with file system directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239544/populate-treeview-with-file-system-directory-structure)

As suggested in comments, I tried using a try catch for this issue, an the error is gone and everything works, however, things like $RECYBLEBIN, Systemvolumeinformation and Binary.data appear as nodes. How to make it so they dont?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've based your code on that post, you could use the `DirectoryInfo.Attributes` property to check for `Hidden` or `System` values, for example, so you could let those items out of your TreeView list.