# How to identify file name on Windows applicatoin that file is clicked on Windows explorer?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, file

Is there any way to get the file details on which user clicks on Windows explorer using C# Windows application.

The user is not modifying, renaming or doing anything with the file, just clicks on a file and gets all details of that file on the click of the file. Like, trigger some event on windows application when the user clicks on any file.

Comment: Instead of using Windows Explorer use equivalent FileDialog inside the c# application.

Comment: @jdweng I want to get the file name clicked on windows explorer without any controls used for load files and list of it.

Comment: Is it is possible, but why do you care if the user selects a file?

Comment: It's *relatively* simple using UI Automation, if you want to try it. There's one *problematic* aspect of it: the ListView (`DUIListView`, the pane on the right), is destroyed each time the View changes or you select a Folder in the Left pane (`SysTreeView32`). So you need to handle a lot of events to be notified when the `DUIListView` is not `Current` anymore: It can't be cached and it needs to be renewed constantly. Except for this detail, it works well enough.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether I have understood your question correctly, but here an idea:
You can build a windows application which consists of tree view which displays the file system (see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239544/populate-treeview-with-file-system-directory-structure)). Then the user can browse in the treeview through different directories and files. When he clicks on a node you can display the information in a lable next to the treeview:

```
FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(pathOfTheClickedNode);
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
label1.Text = $"Filename: {fi.Name},\nLast Access Time: {fi.LastAccessTime},\nFile length: {fi.Length}";
```

Comment: The file will be clicked on Windows Explorer, not on any control of the windows application.